# Как найти повторяющиеся элементы в массивах и составить из них третий массив?

Tags: c++, массивы

Задание: найти повторяющиеся элементы в массивах и составить из них третий массив.

Мой текущий код находит только один повторяющийся элемент. Почему не находит остальные? Также непонятно, как записать полученный массив I.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;


    int main() {
    int r, h, g, G[5], H[3], I[5];
    r = 0;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Vvedite 5 elementov massiva G:";
       for (g = 0;g<5;g++)cin >> G[g];
        cout << "Vvedite 3 elementov massiva H:";
        for (h = 0;h<3;h++)cin >> H[h];
        cout << "Vicisliaem..." << endl;
        g = 0;
        while (g<5) {
            h = 0;
            while (h<3) {
                if (G[g] != H[h]) { h++; }
                else  {I[r] = H[h];r++; };
                break;
            }
            g++;
        }

        for (r = 0;r < 3;r++) { cout << I[r] << "-I-massive" << endl; };
        for (g = 0;g<5;g++) { cout << G[g] << "-G-massive" << "\n"; };
        for (h = 0;h<3;h++) { cout << H[h] << "-H-massive" << "\n"; };
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему вы пользователям вашей программы предлагаете ввести 5 элементов массива  G, когда тот имеет только 4 элемента?

Comment: Вы сначала, при вводе, делаете for g<5, он заканчивается, когда g=5, после этого вы пишете while (g<5), не обнуляя переменную g, разумеется этот ваш цикл уже не срабатывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  #include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include<ctime>


 while (1) {



        int G[4], H[6], K[4], g, h, k,l,m,n;
        k = 0;
        srand(time(0));
        for (g = 0;g < 4;g++) { G[g] = 0 + rand() % 7; }

        for (h = 0; h < 6; h++) { H[h] = 0 + rand() % 7; }

        for (g = 0;g < 4;g++) { cout << G[g] << "\t"; }
        cout << endl;

        for (h = 0; h < 6; h++) { cout << H[h] << "\t"; }
        cout << endl;



        k = 0;

        for (h = 0;h < 6;h++) {
            for (g = 0;g < 4;g++) {



                if (H[h] == G[g]) { K[k] = G[g];k++; }
                else { NULL; }


            }
        }

        for (k = 0;k < 4;k++) { cout << K[k] << "\t"; }
        cout << endl;








        system("pause");
    }
```

Решено.
Только одна проблема - убрать повторяющиеся элементы из конечного массива.

Answer (score 3):

Ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение, потому что в ней происходит обращение к памяти за пределами объявленных массивов.

Например, массив G объявлен, как имеющий 4 элемента

```
int r, h, g, G[4], H[2], I[4];
             ^^^^
```

Допустимый диапазон индексов элементов этого массива `[0-3]`. Однако в последующем цикле вы обращаетесь к несуществующему элементу массива с индексом 4

```
cout << "Vvedite 5 elementov massiva G:";
for (g = 0;g<5;g++)
           ^^^
    cin >> G[g];
```

В результате чего память, не принадлежащая массиву, будет затерта.

То же самое имеет место с массивом `H` , который имеет всего лишь 2 элемента, и для элементов которого допустимый диапазон индексов `[0-1]`

Также у вас имеются ошибки в логике программы. Например после этого цикла

```
    for (g = 0;g<5;g++)
        cin >> G[g];
```

переменная `g` будет равной 5. Это то значение, когда цикл завершит свои итерации. Однако в последующем цикле `while` у вас стоит условие `g < 5`

```
while (g<5) {
//...
```

Очевидно, что это условие не будет истинно, и цикл ни разу не выполнится.
Похоже, вы забыли инициализировать переменную `g` нулем заново перед этим циклом.

Кроме того, например, массив `G` может иметь все элементы, равные одному числу, а массив `H` может содержать только один элемент, равный данному значению. Однако согласно логике выполнения вашей программы, все элементы массива `G` будут писаться в третий массив, так как для каждого элемента массива `G` будет найден единственный элемент в массиве `H`, который равен данному значению. То есть вместо одного элемента массива `G` в результирующий массив запишутся все его элементы.

Кроме того вы не выводите массив `I`, а лишь выводите один его неинициализированный элемент, который также может оказаться за пределами массива

```
cout << I[r] << "-I-massive" << endl;
```

То есть для вывода результирующего массива вам также нужно использовать цикл, естественно, правильно указав диапазон допустимых индексов.